# Running tornado web server with flask application and check asynchronous request handling

Tags: python, flask, tornado

I am trying to run flask application on tornado server to check the asynchronous request handling. I have two files 'flask_req.py' and 'tornado_ex.py'. My both files looks like below:

flask_req.py

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/hello',methods=['GET'])
def hello():
    print "hello 1"
    time.sleep(20)
    x= 2*2
    print(x)
    return "hello"

@app.route('/bye',methods=['GET'])
def bye():
    print "bye 1"
    time.sleep(5)
    y = 4*4
    print(y)
    return "bye"
```

tornado_ex.py

```
from __future__ import print_function
from tornado.wsgi import WSGIContainer
from tornado.web import Application, FallbackHandler
from tornado.websocket import WebSocketHandler
from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop
from tornado import gen
from tornado.httpclient import AsyncHTTPClient
import time
from flask_req import app

class WebSocket(WebSocketHandler):
    def open(self):
        print("Socket opened.")

    def on_message(self, message):
        self.write_message("Received: " + message)
        print("Received message: " + message)

    def on_close(self):
        print("Socket closed.")


@gen.coroutine
def fetch_and_handle():
    """Fetches the urls and handles/processes the response"""

    urls = [
        'http://127.0.0.1:8080/hello',
        'http://127.0.0.1:8080/bye'
    ]

    http_client = AsyncHTTPClient()

    waiter = gen.WaitIterator(*[http_client.fetch(url) for url in urls])

    while not waiter.done():
        try:
            response = yield waiter.next()
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            continue

        print(response.body)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    container = WSGIContainer(app)
    server = Application([
        (r'/websocket/', WebSocket),
        (r'.*', FallbackHandler, dict(fallback=container))
    ])
    server.listen(8080)
    fetch_and_handle()
    IOLoop.instance().start()
```

I want to check the asynchronous behavior of handling the request using tornado server. Right now when I am running it, when both the URL are passed, it is waiting for 20 sec+5sec=25 sec. I want to run it something like that if one request is taking time then it should process the other request so that from above code the total waiting time it should take is only 20 sec, not 25 sec. How I can achieve this behavior here. Right now when I am running the above code as I am getting the response as:

```
$ python tornado_ex.py 
hello 1
4
bye 1
16
hello
bye
```

after printing 'hello1' it's waiting for 25 sec and then doing further processing and after printing 'bye1' it is again waiting for 5sec. What I want is after printing 'hello1', if it is taking so much time then it should process '/bye'.

Comment: Flask is not asynchronous, so to serve multiple requests, it needs multiple threads. But Tornado is single-threaded. So running your Flask app on Tornado will lead to very poor performance. There's even a [warning](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/wsgi.html#tornado.wsgi.WSGIContainer) in the docs about this.

Answer (score 2):

Using the WSGI container means only one request is handled at a time and a subsequent request is not handled until the first is complete.

Using Tornado to run WSGI applications is generally not a good idea when you need concurrency.

Either use multiple processes or convert you project to use ASYNC TornadoWeb framework instead of WSGI.

Comment: Can you please tell what changes I should do in code to use async tornado web framework?

Comment: For that you really need to go read the TornadoWeb documentation properly and work through their examples to work it out. http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/

Comment: okay Thanks for the help :)